# Passing data from a ModelBinder to a custom InputFormatter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, modelbinder, inputformatter

The **Context**: In a WebAPI under Asp.net Core 2.1, I must create a POST endpoint, 
 `[server]/MyController/{Parameter1}/MoreRouteThing/`. I have to create a custom `IInputFormatter` because the body isn't readable by the default formatters.

The **Problem**: To be able to format the input, the `IInputFormatter` need to know the value of `Parameter1`.

I implemented a custom `IModelBinder` that handles this model, wired everything in `startup.cs` using a custom `IModelBinderProvider` (probably overkill, but I wanted to understand the whole chain.)

Within the custom `IModelBinder`, I can access `{Parameter1}` using something akin `bindingContext.ActionContext.RouteData.Values["Parameter1"]`, but I have no idea how to pass that to the `IInputFormatter`. The former passes an `InputFormatterContext` to the latter, but nothing within that context object seems appropriate to store extra information.

So the **Question**: How to pass data from the `IModelBinder` to the `IInputFormatter`? Should I instead parse the url/route directly from the `IInputFormatter`, hence making it aware of "where" it's located within the whole process? (seems unclean to me.)

Answer (score 0):

The list of all formatters is transmitted through the constructor of the modelbinder and in the future one is selected that matches the specified condition. More details can be found in the source code:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/BodyModelBinder.cs
and
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/BodyModelBinderProvider.cs

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for posting an answer. It's preferred to [omit salutations in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).